# why did this spybot installer install opera without my consent?

Tags: virus

[link to questionable installer](https://www.filehorse.com/download-spybot-search-destroy/?utm_medium=win&utm_source=safer-networking.org&utm_campaign=Spybot)

this is the legitimate page to download spybot by the way (the manufacturer's website provides 3 links and i chose this one)

upon installing it opera was automatically launched on my device even tho i had never installed it and i found this

[image: opera most downloaded browser on the installers page]

there is also the theory that some malware might have installed opera and not the installer. but that would make absolutely no sense seeing how opera was launched and installed the moment the installation of spybot began.

Comment: We cannot provide explanation what happened here, since we have no insight of what the vendor might have decided to bundle, the downloading site might have decided to bundle or some attacker might have done with your system ... . There is only your word of what you observed but not context to determine what happened in the background and why. Also, we don't do any security evaluation of arbitrary websites, links or files here.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich i believe it could be an attacker but i find it unlikely because the system is virus scanned pretty much weekly and examined for things like weird start up programs or odd tcp connections

Comment: A lot of download sites will put wrappers around installers that also install 3rd party apps.  Best to go directly to the author's web site to download the installer.  It's possible that the wrapper installed Opera along with the software.  (And Opera imported bookmarks automatically?  Are those yours?)